# TortoiseSVN vs Subversion

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When tortoiseSVN is used w/o a server, is subversion still involved? Is subversion just a server? I'm not clear on the demarcation between tortoiseSVN as "client" to subversion, and tortoiseSVN as being able to work by itself,  using a repository on the local drive.  So what does subversion  bring?  Just the ability to "server" from a remote computer?

Answer (score 2):

I think the word client seems to be confusing you a lot more than it should. Subversion is not a server and clients can be local. However, there is nothing about a client-server relationship that requires them to be on separate machines.

> In Computer science, **client-server** is a software architecture model consisting of two parts, client systems and server systems, both communicating over a computer network or on the same computer.

Subversion can be used on a separate server, but is not required to be on one. It is simply a version control system. Nothing more. TortoiseSVN is an interface for Subversion, and to put it in the most facetious way possible, meaning you can actually click stuff on your screen as opposed to just using the command line. The symbols and things that you're referring to, do not come with subversion by default. It's a feature of the TortoiseSVN interface.

TortoiseSVN *depends on* subversion so the question "So what does subversion bring?" is rather self-defeating.

Comment: I installed what is called "TortoiseSVN" and I can use it w/o a server. So YES it can work with out a Server. I see little icons on files and everything.  So the "ToroiseSVN" installation INCLUDES the ability to manage versions of files. Is that ability provided by "SUBVERSION"? What is SUBVERSION then? just an API? just a protocol?.  It seems that the "server" is only to serve files to multiple clients.  People, you need to stop just assuming you understand what's being ask and regurgitate rehearsed responses. And spare me the attitude and facetiousness. Show some discipline.

Comment: I literally don't even know where to begin with this asinine response from you. Reading is clearly not your strong point so let me go sentence by sentence. 1) "So YES it can work with out a Server". Obviously.. Because I JUST said that. Your computer is a server. Subversion is a **VERSION CONTROL SYSTEM**. Your computer acts as the server.

Comment: 2) "I see little icons on files and everything. So the "ToroiseSVN" installation INCLUDES the ability to manage versions of files. Is that ability provided by "SUBVERSION"?" ----- Again, because if you learn to read, I literally explained that TortoiseSVN is an interface for subversion. **SUBVERSION IS THE VERSION CONTROL SYSTEM THAT ALLOWS YOU MANAGE VERSIONS OF FILES**.

Comment: 3) "What is SUBVERSION then? just an API? just a protocol?" ----- _Again_ you seem to be asking the same question 17 different ways and every time someone, including myself, answers you, you don't even bother to read it. **SUBVERSION IS THE VERSION CONTROL SYSTEM THAT ALLOWS YOU TO MANAGE VERSIONS OF FILES. YOUR COMPUTER IS THE SERVER IT RUNS ON.** Things like `svn update` and `svn checkout` are things that **SUBVERSION** allows you to do.

Comment: 4) **TORTOISESVN IS AN INTERFACE... WHAT THIS INTERFACE DOES IS _USE_ SUBVERSION -- SUBVERSION BEING THE VERSION CONTROL SYSTEM. HOWEVER, THIS LETS YOU SEE THE LITTLE SYMBOLS ON YOUR SCREEN AND YOU CAN RIGHT CLICK ON THEM. THIS IS A FEATURE OF TORTOISESVN... OTHERWISE IF YOU WERE _ONLY_ USING SUBVERSION (WHEREAS TORTOISESVN SITS ON TOP OF SUBVERSION) YOU WOULD HAVE TO USE THE COMMAND LINE.

Comment: @user3145004 4) "People, you need to stop just assuming you understand what's being ask and regurgitate rehearsed responses. And spare me the attitude and facetiousness. Show some discipline." ------- You have a number of people trying to explain the difference between Subversion and TortoiseSVN and you can't seem to take the basic reading comprehension skills to even try to determine what people are saying to you. I was being facetious because you can't seem to understand the correct terminology given to you by 3 different people, so I had to try to explain it to you like a child. Didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Tortoise is a pluqin for Windows Explorer. It is a Subversion client that gives you a visual interface to Subversion and without it you would have to use the command-line client, as in `svn status` to see if files in your working copy have been changed. It is Tortoise that provides those icons. But it is the Subversion server that provides the repository and checks stuff in.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what "TortoiseSVN" includes. I installed "TortoiseSVN" (one word) version 1.9.7, It seems that I can use it on a repository on the same computer.  So does "TortoiseSVN" contains more than a 'client' ?  Does it contain a smaller version of "SVN"?

Comment: It's more than a client.  You can use it w/o a server

Comment: That's hogwash. It's a Subversion client.

Comment: If you have your Subversion repository on the same computer, then Tortoise is talking to `svnserve`, which is the Subversion server. Shut that service down and see how far you get checking stuff in from Tortoise.

Comment: Page 2 of the PDF manual states : "For the purposes of this tutorial we are going to use Subversion's local repository feature which allows direct access to a repository created on your hard drive without needing a server at all." So what do I need? What am I using? If not a server, than what???

Comment: Here more from the TortoiseSVN manual "The local repository feature is very useful for test and evaluation but unless you are working as a
sole developer on one PC you should always use a proper Subversion server." Is that "hogwash" ? Or can TortoiseSVN be used w/o a server? Or is the  manual wrong?

Comment: @BoarGules you are mistaken about `svnserve`.

Comment: Tortoise is a Subversion client. *Any* Subversion client (and not just Tortoise) can use the Subversion `file://` access method to work with a repository on a local disk. So, Tortoise is not "more than a client." But there are significant drawbacks to using a local repository, which the Tortoise manual is very clear about: "Although in theory it is possible to put a FSFS repository on a network share and have multiple users access it using `file://` protocol, this is most definitely not recommended." Even if you are a single user on a single machine, `svnserve` is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

> When tortoiseSVN is used w/o a server, is subversion still involved?

Yes.

> Is subversion just a server?

No.

TortoiseSVN is a SVN client and SVN client can [operate with a local repository directly via the `file://` URL](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-access). When you use the `file://` access, you don't contact any server at all (neither `svnserve` nor Apache). Any Subversion repository can be accessed by Subversion client via file:// and no server is required for that. However, in such case the repository is accessible only locally.